# Sorry, something went wrong: Facebook login with next.js & next-auth

Tags: facebook, next.js, next-auth

[image]I want to use the next-auth package in order to setup login with facebook.

During the development `npm run dev` it works fine, and I am able to login in with Facebook. Unfortunately when deployed it does not work. I do not know what is wrong. Did anyone have this problem? Link to the demo page https://front-demo-sigma.vercel.app/

Answer (score 7):

In your Facebook app, go to **>Use Cases>Authentication & Account Creation** and check if you have all the permissions you need.

I had the same issue, in my case I didnt have the email permission activated, after that it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that next-auth ask for email and username, username is given by default but not email, so you have to enable email first, then you have to apply for a validation, it takes a while then you could you ask for user data